# How to implement a boostrap template into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a relatively new ruby programmer and i'm looking to implement this boostrap template:

https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/

into a rails application  but im not exactly sure how to go about it. I noticed it uses LESS but i believe rails uses SASS so are there some conversions im going to have to do? It'd be nice if someone could give me a brief number of steps on how to make this work in rails.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to solve this problem myself this morning. Admin LTE is awesome, enjoy:

### Install the Gem:

(From the [project documentation](https://github.com/shine60vn/adminlte-rails#installation) on GitHub)

Add the gem to your application's `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'adminlte-rails'
```

Then run `bundle` to install the Gem:

```
$ bundle
```

Alternatively, you can install it with the `gem` command:

```
$ gem install adminlte-rails
```

---

### Integrate Into Your Project:

Finally, in order to integrate the theme with the other stylesheets of your project, add the following to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require admin-lte
```

And add the following to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require font-awesome
*= require ionicons
*= require admin-lte
```

After that, you should be able to style your Project using all of the classes installed via the AdminLTE template. Let me know if you run into any other snags, I'll be working with the theme extensively while putting together a dashboard app as a front-end for a larger project.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to install AdminLTE (and Font Awesome) via *Bower*, follow the instructions below:

I assume you have installed Bower. Otherwise, see [Install Bower](http://bower.io/#install-bower).

Create `.bowerrc` as follows:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

Run `bower init` command to create `bower.json`. You can hit the *Enter* key to every questions.

Add `vendor/assets/bower_components` to your `.gitignore` if you manage your source code with Git.

Install AdminLTE and Font Awesome:

```
$ bower install admin-lte font-awesome --save
```

Add following lines to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require admin-lte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap
//= require admin-lte
```

Insert following lines into `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` before the last line:

```
 *= require admin-lte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap
 *= require admin-lte
 *= require font-awesome
```

[UPDATE]

You need to read the following article in order to use font-awesome installed by Bower in *production* mode.

https://github.com/platanus/guides/blob/master/setup/fontawesome-bower-rails.md

Answer (score 1):

In general, according to this [post by Ivan Storck](http://www.codefellows.org/blog/5-ways-to-manage-front-end-assets-in-rails) you could use one of the following appraoches

1. <del>Download from Source</del>
2. <del>Use a Ruby Gem Including a Rails Engine</del> (described by @devynspencer)
3. <del>Use Bower and Configure Rails</del> (described by @Tsutomo)
4. Use the `Bower-Rails` gem (rake style)
5. Use [Rails-Assets.org](https://rails-assets.org/) (bundler style)

Approach 4 and 5 are more **up-to-date** than *Gem* version (No. 2) and **cleaner** than *using two systems* (No. 3) to manage dependencies. (Just my opinion and [@1.44mb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894705/1-44mb) has [different opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019454/how-to-implement-a-boostrap-template-into-rails/30047619?noredirect=1#comment51350816_30047619) in the following comment.)

I changed from gem version to Rails-Assets.org and needed minimum changes in `application.js` and `application.css.scss`. However, I needed to add `skin-blue.css` to one of my assets path and `application.css.scss` file.

Please do read the post by Ivan Storck and see the respective links to learn more.

- [rails-assets](http://rails-assets.org)
- [bower-rails](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails)

Comment: I prefer using Bower for frontend dependencies (css and js to be specific) and gems for rails specific dependencies. I think it is the best way to manage big projects. That said i think #3 is my way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1+, there is now an offical sass port of the project.  See: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass